# How to return all items in an ObservableCollection which satisfy a condition C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find a neat way to find all of the values in an observable collection which meet a certain criteria. For this example to keep things simple lets say its the collection contains ints and I'm trying to find all of the items that are greater than 5.

The best way I currently know of doing it is like this

```
ObservableCollection<Int> findAllGreaterThanFive (ObservableCollection<Int> numbers)
{
    ObservableCollection<Int> numbersGreaterThanFive;

    foreach(Int number in numbers)
    {
        if (number > 5)
        {
            numbersGreaterThanFive.add(number);    
        }
    }

    return numbersGreaterThanFive;
}
```

Obviously ignore any simple solutions that take advantage to the fact I'm looking for ints I need a solution that works with any an ObservableCollection of any type with any condition. I was just wondering if checking every item with the foreach loop and the conditional is the best way of doing it?

Comment: why are you returning a new collection?

Comment: Send in the filter as 2nd parameter of your method. Use a Func<int,bool> in this case.

Comment: I would say use LINQ. Deferred execution is your friend, in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use System.Linq namespace, add using statement `using System.Linq` and after that you can use following `Where` method.

```
ObservableCollection<int> list = new ObservableCollection<int>();
list.Where(i => i > 5).ToList();
```

you can use any kind of objects like :

```
ObservableCollection<DataItem> list = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>();
list.Where(i => i.ID > 10);
```

The code above returns DataItem's with ID greater than 10.

If you sure about there's only one record satisfying condition, you can use `First()` method like :

```
ObservableCollection<DataItem> list = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>();
list.First(i => i.ID == 10);
```

Above code returns the DataItem with ID 10. But if there's no record with ID = 10 then it will throw an exception. Avoid of this if you're not sure there's only one record satisfies the condition. Also you can use `FirstOrDefault()` method.

```
ObservableCollection<DataItem> list = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>();
    DataItem item = list.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ID == 10);
if(item != null)
{
 //DoWork
}
```

If there's no record with ID = 10, then item will be null.

Answer (score 9):

You can say something like:

```
var numbersGreaterThanFive = numbers.Where(x => x > 5);
```

Comment: To expand on this, you can use an IComparable instead of the ">" and a variable instead of "5" to satisfy, the last part of the question.

Comment: especially, `return new ObservableCollection<Int>(numbers.Where(x => x > 5))`.

Comment: You can use `.ToList()` method also. e.g. `var numbersGreaterThanFive = numbers.Where(x => x > 5).ToList();`

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I'm trying to make a windows universal app btw if that changes anything and I'm using a custom class as my type, I get the error System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<App.customClass> does not contain a definition for 'Where'

Comment: If LINQ is not possible my answer will indeed not work (you should have add it to the tags though).  I don't understand why the accepted answer works ok (also uses Where).